# PhantomJS and SoundCloud embed

Tags: phantomjs, soundcloud

I'm building an application that relies on Soundcloud.
Whenever I load this page, all of the postMessages of the Soundcloud event have the value null.

My endpoint looks like this, `http://localhost:3000/rap/video/157681`

Examples,

When I attach this snippet, I can see what's going on.

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};
```

This shows me the follow:

```
received message {"widgetId":"widget_1438463010590","method":"getDuration","value":null} from https://w.soundcloud.com
received message {"widgetId":"widget_1438463010590","method":"ready","value":null} from https://w.soundcloud.com
received message {"widgetId":"widget_1438463010590","method":"error","value":null} 
from https://w.soundcloud.com
```

I don't have this issue when I'm not using PhantomJS. (ie if I load the same endpoint with Chrome).

The expected response looks like this, (which is what I get when running in a real browser).

```
received message {"widgetId":"widget_1438462797950","method":"getDuration","value":46528} from https://w.soundcloud.com
received message {"widgetId":"widget_1438462797950","method":"getCurrentSound","value":{"id":215298719,"resource_type":"sound","playable":true,"kind":"track","created_at":"2015/07/18 18:48:55 +0000","user_id":156179640,"duration":46528,"commentable":true,"state":"finished","original_content_size":8194532,"last_modified":"2015/07/18 18:49:04 +0000","sharing":"public","tag_list":"CGY Calgary Stampede Wild Rap Hiphop Rappad","permalink":"wild-west","streamable":true,"embeddable_by":"all","downloadable":false,"purchase_url":null,"label_id":null,"purchase_title":null,"genre":null,"title":"Wild West","description":null,"label_name":null,"release":null,"track_type":"recording","key_signature":null,"isrc":null,"video_url":null,"bpm":null,"release_year":null,"release_month":null,"release_day":null,"original_format":"wav","license":"cc-by","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/215298719","user":{"id":156179640,"kind":"user","permalink":"nxplicit","username":"Erik Soby","last_modified":"2015/07/29 15:40:17 +0000","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/156179640","permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/nxplicit","avatar_url":"https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000155555549-4ur1q9-large.jpg"},"created_with":{"id":45176,"kind":"app","name":"Ableton Live","uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/apps/45176","permalink_url":"http://soundcloud.com/apps/ableton-live","external_url":"http://www.ableton.com/free-trial"},"permalink_url":"https://soundcloud.com/nxplicit/wild-west","artwork_url":null,"waveform_url":"https://w1.sndcdn.com/kMqYHwA5fBzl_m.png","stream_url":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/215298719/stream","playback_count":310,"download_count":0,"favoritings_count":0,"comment_count":0,"likes_count":0,"reposts_count":0,"attachments_uri":"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/215298719/attachments","policy":"ALLOW","monetization_model":"NOT_APPLICABLE","publisher_info":{},"_resource_id":215298719,"_resource_type":"sound"}} from https://w.soundcloud.com
```

**Some progress**

I added this snippet to the PhantomJS, and I'm able to get a result.

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  var widget = SC.Widget('ui-id-1')
  widget.getDuration(function(callback) {
    console.log('getDuration called');
    console.log(callback);
  });
});
```

In the command line this returns,

```
getDuration called
46528
received message {"widgetId":"widget_1438464901479","method":"getDuration","value":46528} from https://w.soundcloud.com
```

So perhaps the issue isn't with Soundcloud at all.

Comment: The problem is that "value" here is null, when it shouldn't be.

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't support any type of sound, so you won't be able to use PhantomJS to load tracks. Soundcloud probably detects that the audio cannot be played, so it doesn't bother to load it.